# i18n database tables get value of a field by culture

Tags: database, internationalization, translation

I am in the process of internationalising my application. Lets say I have a table like this:

`task_priority`:

```
id | description
```

Then I create a table called `table_priority_i18n`:

```
id | culture | description
```

where id and culture are the primary key and id is foreign key to `task_priority` id.

To get the description I am making a left join between to tables

```
select tp.id, t.description 
from task_priority tp 
  left join task_priority_i18n t 
    on t.id = tp.id and t.culture = :culture.
```

But I would like to change my query so if there is not a translation in the i18n table it returns the value from the base table.

I know that I could remove that column I only use the i18n table but at the moment is too much work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select tp.id, NVL( t.description, tp.description)
from task_priority tp 
  left outer join task_priority_i18n t 
    on t.id = tp.id 
    and t.culture = :culture
```